Why is Gmail grouping emails together that are different subject lines and similar but still different groups of people?
So Gmail does this thing where it groups conversations. Usually it’s great but sometimes it gets it really wrong. I’d like to turn if off or at least find a way to differentiate the emails easier.
For example, I have a hockey team so I send out emails often to everyone about games and events. At the same time, there is a surprise party being planned for one of my teammates, so there is a separate email with him removed, and a few other friends added. Gmail has grouped these two conversations and I don’t know why as there are different subject lines and different recipients.
This is also now terrifying for me that someone else with gmail is going to not pay attention, respond to the wrong email, and spoil the surprise.
How do I stop Gmail from doing this?

Turn off conversation view. Always start new conversations with a new email.
